# simulate ctrl+alt+del in windows 7 remote computer

Tags: windows, windows-7, remote-desktop

I have a requirement of simulating <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> in remote system.I loaded `sas.dll` and called sendsas function but it is not working.How to display winlogon screen on remote system.

Thanks

Comment: What software are you using to connect?

Comment: By default, only ease-of-access applications can use the SendSAS function.  This and additional requirements are described in the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd979761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: VS2008,writing own remote desktop sharing application.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed [here](https://superuser.com/q/492856/287844), you can try using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> instead. This will bring up the Task Manager.

If this doesn't work for what you need, you can open the on-screen keyboard in the remote desktop, and click the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> keys with the mouse.

Comment: Thanks,i wanted to capture the winlogon desktop,now only default desktop is displaying.how to capture the winlogon desktop in windows 7